# NotInList Error after adding an item through a pop-up form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform (frmAdicionarPersonagens) which has, among other commands, a combobox named cboPersonagem.

I can add new items to the combo through the NotInList event in the usual way by using an action query (INSERT INTO tblListaPersonagens… etc.).

Now, I want to do the same, but using another form (frmAddPersonagem), linked to table tblListaPersonagens, which is fired in modal mode (so the user is forced to close that form with the added item before returning to the subform frmAdicionarPersonagens and the combo cboPersonagem.

The point is, I want the form fired to check for typos and also to add some data (which I supressed here to simplify the problem).

When there are no typos, that is, when the word entered in the combo is not changed in the frmAddPersonagem, everything runs smoothly. However, if I edit the word (for whatever reason) when I close frmAddPersonagem, I get the usual error “the item is not in the list”. However, the “new” word is in fact in the list and I don’t know what is happening, or how can I get out of this problem.

My code for not in list event:

```
Private Sub cboPersonagem_NotInList(NewChar As String, Response As Integer)
'
'   Show a Yes/No message and get the result.
    Dim ButtonClicked As Integer
    ButtonClicked = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you want to add """ & NewChar & """ as a new Character?", _
                    Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Title:="Character not in the list")
'
    If ButtonClicked = vbNo Then
'
        cboPersonagem.Undo

        Response = acDataErrContinue

    ElseIf ButtonClicked = vbYes Then
    
        ' Add in table "tblListaPersonagens" a new record with the new Character written in the form
'        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblListaPersonagens(NomePersonagem) VALUES('" & NewChar & "')"
'        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    
        DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmAddPersonagem", WindowMode:=acDialog, OpenArgs:=NewChar

        Response = acDataErrAdded
            
        Me.cboPersonagem.Undo
        
        Me.cboPersonagem.Requery
        
        Me.cboPersonagem = DMax("IDPersonagem", "tblListaPersonagens")
'
    End If
'
End Sub
```

Comment: I just relearned why I don't use the not in list event.   The code is old and buggy.  Instead,  I just add a button that opens my add/edit data form. 
 Anyway, you should be able to get the code working by deleting all the statements using me after setting response = AcDataErrAdded. I suspect this is an example of issues with setting control properties inside control events but I gave up on testing that hypothesis because of bugs.

Comment: @mazoula, Not sure what you mean by 'old and buggy'. Working just fine for me. Except for not returning focus to combobox after popup closes. Maybe that's the 'bug' or something weird about my form?

Comment: If you go to the microsoft documentation for the notinlist event for a bound combobox you will find errors in the example.  Also, today would you do things like setting the combobox value to null allows requery?  Finally most of the time comboboxes are used for foreign keys and in this case the notinlist event works correctly.  But if you add a notinlistevent to a combobox for a column like firstname in a persons table then when you add a new person with a new firstname you add 2 rows to the persons table not 1.  I assume the notinlistevent is adding a second person but haven't proven that yet

Comment: Not a great example for your case. Why would you have a combobox for entering a firstname or any other name parts in Persons table? Name part fields should just be free entry textboxes. A combobox would be for selecting a person for input of PersonID as foreign key into another table and that combobox could have NotInList code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need both `acDataErrAdded` and `Requery`.

If you want to be able to edit the NewData passed to popup form, set the combobox to Null then populate it after new record edit is saved. I would be hesitant to use DMax() in a database with multiple simultaneous users. An Alternative is code behind the popup to:

1. directly set value of combobox (see example below) or
2. set a global or TempVars variable then the calling form uses that to set combobox value

```
Private Sub Combo29_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim sMsg As String
    'initialize response to error
    Response = acDataErrContinue
   
    'Ask if user wants to add a new item
    sMsg = "'" & NewData & "' is not in the current list. " _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Do you want to add it? "
    Me.Combo29 = Null    
    If MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo, "Add New Data") = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Holidays", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog, NewData
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
    Me.Combo29.SetFocus
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then Me.HolName = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
_______________________________________________________
Private Sub Form_Close()
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then Forms!Misc.Combo29 = Me.HolID
End Sub
```